# ACL, AROs and ACOs, how to update them if there are new sections?

Tags: cakephp, acl

I'm trying to understand how use `AROs` and `ACOs` if I've added a section in my site.

The `CakePHP` guide is clear on how the concept of `ACL` works, but not on how it should be implemented in the code. Personally I've found all the part of the tutorial very unclear on how they should be used inside `CakePHP` framework. It seems to be most unfriendly part of `CakePHP` framework.

Now when I go in new sections I've created, I get this error, and I don't understand how I could fix it.

```
Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.  Node references:
Aro: Array
(
    [User] => Array (
        [id] => 1
        [username] => vittorio
        [group_id] => 1
        [created] => 2011-03-30 10:51:23
        [modified] => 2011-03-30 10:51:23
        [viewable] => 0
    )

)

Aco: controllers/Works/index [CORE/cake/libs/controller/components/acl.php, line 273]
```

If I look on 
http://book.cakephp.org/view/647/An-Automated-tool-for-creating-ACOs
and on
http://book.cakephp.org/view/996/Creating-Components#!/view/1548/Creating-ACOs-Access-Control-Objects

I should get the answers, but if I run this code calling the url `mysite.com/build_acl` again I only get these errors:

```
Missing Controller

Error: BuildAclController could not be found.

Error: Create the class BuildAclController below in file: app/controllers/build_acl_controller.php

<?php
    class BuildAclController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'BuildAcl';
}
?>

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/views/errors/missing_controller.ctp
```

Does exist a decent guide who talks about `ACL`, `AROs` and `ACOs` and how to implement them on `CakePHP` without leave the reader lost?

Comment: I haven't found one. I would recommend coming up with one of your own. It's a lot easier than dealing with the headache of Cake's ACL stuff

Comment: @Nick, first point you mention should be invalidated by my post. The second point you mention would most likely lead to an equivalent of the ACL system, as you would try to implement the most generic solution access control solution with the fewest requirements on space (avoiding a huge sparse matrix). In terms of a programmers API few on the new systems, the gain would be zero. If all you want to do is implement a quick-and-dirty row-level-access system, then there are ways to do it. But do not mix this up with implementing an ACL system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vittorio,

with due respect, ACL and AUTH combined are a very generic tool. Getting it to work for the first time annoyed me quite a bit. The main errors, which I keep seeing over and over again are:

- **Not** calling `build_acl` after one or more new actions has been created.
- **Not** initializing the newly arisen setup (fresh `ACL` nodes as output of
  the previous step) with proper access
  rights.
- **Not** calling `parent::beforeFilter()` in every controller who inherits from parent `app_controller` (as often crucial settings reside in this method).
- Trying to save a foobared setup instead of going over the Auth+Acl tutorial at the end of the book again. It works (no offense), many people accomplished it before, so you can, too (I do not say that it is accomplished instantaneously).
- Reinventing the wheel: After a basic functioning Auth+Acl [tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application), check out the plugins on *sourceforge* and *github*.
- **Not** reinventing the wheel ^^, afaik the perfect AUTH+ACL management plugin is yet to be written (but useable code does exist)

Good journey, Benjamin.

**Edit0**
Basic code hygiene helps, e.g. if you allow users as requesting objects and actions as controlled objects, it makes sense to write the `build_acl()` into the users_controller, directly followed by, e.g. `init_db()`, where you centralize settings access rights.
Do not forget to remove these hacks before going into production, even though setting correct access rights again would not hurt much, but imagine what john doe and friends do to your app if they run this function all the time Ü

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I just said I didn't understood the ACL part because I'm not used to use it (OOP Flash developer).

Comment: @vittorio, I did not intend to offend you by being verbose. I just felt writing down recurrent issues in a central place would not only help you but in addition other as well. From what I have read, others, not you alone, struggle here. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

```
mysite.com/build_acl
```

you must run build_acl in any action of your controller, you can't call it like that you're referring to an action without controller. at least you can try like this

```
mysite.com/{my_controller}/build_acl
```

or run it in app_controller's beforeFilter method e.g.

```
function beforeFilter(){
  $this->build_acl();
}
```

of course the function itself must be declared in app_controller.